# Annuity Duration Based on Closed Derivative is half of Effective Duration?

Tags: bond, duration

I am analyzing an annuity with a stub. I calculate the effective duration as 
(P(-10bps) - P(+10bps))/(2*Principal * (.001))

I then take the derivative of the standard annuity formula discounted by a stub period divided by the initial price and evaluate it and find that it is half of the effective duration.

It is known that effective duration is a pretty damn good approximation so I know it's in a tight ballpark; what I dont understand is why the derivative is coming up as exactly half.

I checked my work in symbolic maths programs.

Ideas?